Existence of an almost bijective function satisfying a condition.
The following question is a restricted continuation (for $p=2$) of a previous question.
Let $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Suppose there exists $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $0\leq k\leq n$ and $2\mid \lfloor m/2^k\rfloor$. Define $\widehat{k}(n,m) = \max\left\{k: 0\leq k\leq n,\, 2\mid \lfloor m/2^k\rfloor\right\}$.
Let $\sigma : \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ be defined as
$$\sigma (n,m) = \begin{cases}
m + 2^{\widehat{k}(n,m)} + 2^{\widehat{k}(n,m)+1} - 2^{n+1}, &\text{if } \exists 0\leq k\leq n \text{ such that } 2\mid \lfloor m/2^k\rfloor,\\
m + 1 - 2^{n+1}, &\text{otherwise}. 
\end{cases}$$
Question: Does there exist an injective function $\psi : \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ satisfying the following conditions?

The set $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \setminus \psi\left(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\right)$ is a nonempty finite set.
$\psi\left(\sigma(n,m)\right) = \sigma\left(n,\psi(m)\right)$ for each $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.

It appears to me that such a function may not exist, but I am unable to provide a proof. I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Have you found a function that's not injective, but still satisfies the main two conditions?

Don't define $\hat k$ in the definition of $\sigma.$ Start by defining $\hat k$ first.

And there is no need to reference $2$-adic numbers here. This function is only defined  on integers, not $2$-adic integers, and the function doesn't come even close to requiring knowledge of $2$-adic numbers, so your title might not attract people who can help but don't feel comfortable with $p$-adic numbers.

If you fix $m$ and consider $n$ such that $2^n>\max(m,\psi(m))$, you get the relation $\psi(m+2^n)=\psi(m)+2^n$. If you do this with $m=0$, and repeat this process, I think you can show that $\psi(n)=\psi(0)+n$ if $n$ is divisible by $2^k$ where $2^k$ is such that $2^k>\psi(0)$. Not sure how useful this is though.
